# How to handle that browser connection couldnt be established with Testcafe

Tags: testing, azure-devops, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Im running my TestCafe tests on a Azure DevOps agent.

I'm experiencing sporadic issue of browser connectivity:

```
1 of 2 browser connections have not been established:
- firefox:userProfile

Hints:
- Increase the value of the "browserInitTimeout" option if it is too low (currently: 2 minutes for local browsers and 6 minutes for remote browsers). This option determines how long TestCafe waits for browsers to be ready.
- The error can also be caused by network issues or remote device failure. Make sure that your network connection is stable and you can reach the remote device.
```

The ":userProfile" was a suggestion to fix the issue, but it doesnt seem to work.

How can I handle this issue so that my tests doesnt fail and becomes unreliable?

Also Im experiencing that my tests becomes even more unreliable if I add a third browser (chrome, firefox, edge) - any suggestions on how to avoid that as well?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that using ":userProfile" can help fix the issue.

The error indicates that a browser doesn't send an HTTP request to the TestCafe server. If this happens sporadically, the likely cause is the lack of resources (CPU/memory). When the performance is low, the connection cannot be established during the timeout specified by the TestCafe.

It seems to me that the correct way to fix the issue is to increase the resources on your CI machine or decrease the number of browser instances.

Comment: But since its an Azure DevOps agent I cant increase the resources. I can accept a sporadic failure but Im looking for a way to run the tests again.

Comment: If the "browserInitTimeout" option does not help, try to separate the task that runs TestCafe in multiple browsers into multiple CI tasks (one task for each browser).

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the similar issues, one thing which i did was, to update browserInitTimeout value from 2 mins to 4 mins (240000) in .testcaferc.json file. you may not find this page directly so try to search it. (Ctrl+Shift+f is the command for VSCode)